# Placing points dynamically in a Raphael arc path

Tags: javascript, geometry, raphael

I am developing a radar which consists of concentric circular sectors using Raphael JS library. I have been able to create these sectors, however, I am having difficulty thinking up a suitable solution of how points (which are basically simple Raphael shapes- circles, triangles, etc) can be placed within each sector.
I am not sure but does a possible solution lie in using the getBBox() for each path? Keeping in mind that the bounding box for circular shapes have points that are not within the shape itself.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a random invisible path inside the region

get a random point inside that path

and draw a random object using that point as center

```
var radius1 = 80;
var radius2 = 50;
var center = 250;
function circleToPath(c, r, d) {
  if(d == 1) {
    return "M "+(c-r)+","+c+" q 0,-"+r+" "+r+",-"+r+" "+r+",0 "+r+","+r+" 0,"+r+" -"+r+","+r+" -"+r+",0 "+"-"+r+",-"+r;
  } else {
    return "M "+(c-r)+","+c+" q 0,"+r+" "+r+","+r+" "+r+",0 "+r+",-"+r+" 0,-"+r+" -"+r+",-"+r+" -"+r+",0 "+"-"+r+","+r;
  }
}
region = paper.path(circleToPath(center, radius1, 1) + circleToPath(center, radius2, 0) + "z").attr({fill: "red", "fill-opacity": 0.5,stroke: "none"});
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  randomRadius = Math.floor((Math.random() * (radius1 - radius2)) + radius2);
  vir = paper.path(circleToPath(center, randomRadius, 1)).attr({fill: "none", stroke: "none"});
  len = vir.getTotalLength();
  pointCenter = vir.getPointAtLength(Math.floor(Math.random() * len));
  paper.circle(pointCenter.x,pointCenter.y,(Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)) + 5);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5L9g0xh4/

UPDATE:

A little bit cheating as path intersection exists but is not working well in Raphael

constrain the random point and then rotate each: 
http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/opqhas0w/

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems to be a solution, however, because of the randomness, there is the possibility of an overlap of the points (objects) which I would not want. Is there a way to avoid this happening?

Comment: Hmm...seems like a lot of hack :). I give it a try and let you know how I get on. Many thanks for the help.